# Extracting data from a ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need to extract the URL's from the php datas, how can i achieve this?

PHP

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM picture LIMIT 3';
$result = mysql_query($query);


while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $url.=$rec['pic_location'].";";
}

echo json_encode($url);
```

Ajax

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".goButton").click(function() {
       var dir =  $(this).attr("id");

   var imId = $(".theImage").attr("id");
   $.ajax({
      url: "viewnew.php",
      data: {
         current_image: imId,
         direction    : dir
      },
     success: function(ret){
          console.log(ret);
          var arr = ret;
          alert("first: " + arr[0] + ", second: " + arr[1]);
          alert(arr[0]);
          $(".theImage").attr("src", +arr[0]);
          if ('prev' == dir) {
        imId ++;
     } else {
        imId --;
     }
     $("#theImage").attr("id", imId);
          }
       });

    });
    });
    </script>
```

the alert message isn't working its just printing H T  ( i think these are http://... )

Comment: What does the console.log shows?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  this happend on `$(".theImage").attr("src", +arr[0]);`  and the `alert(arr[0]);` shows the proper URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a string which is not parsed as JSON.
Just add `dataType: "json"` to the ajax settings.

And since you're reading it as an array in your javascript you should return it like so:

```
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $url[] = $rec['pic_location'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i am getting a valid message now in the alert box:) but  why isnt the Scr of image changing ? `alert(arr[0]);
    $(".theImage").attr("src", +arr[0]);`  the inspect element shows Src=NaN

Comment: Remove the + since you don't want to calculate anything. JS now assumes you mean 0+arr[0]

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a string in your PHP and expecting an array as response in javascript. Change you PHP to

```
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $url[] = $rec['pic_location'];
}
```

And javascript to

```
$.ajax({
      url: "viewnew.php",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
         current_image: imId,
         direction    : dir
      },
      success: function(ret){
          console.log(ret[0]);
          var arr = ret;
          alert(arr);  
          alert("first: " + arr[0] + ", second: " + arr[1]);    // THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!!
          if ('prev' == dir) {
            imId ++;
         } else {
            imId --;
         }
         $("#theImage").attr("id", imId);
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thank you , i am getting a valid message now in the alert box:) but  why isnt the Scr of image changing ? `alert(arr[0]);
    $(".theImage").attr("src", +arr[0]);`  the inspect element shows Src=NaN

Comment: don't use `+arr[0]` and also put an `alert(arr[0])` to see what are you actually setting the `src` attribute to